# How to work with SQLite like data in Python

Tags: python

I want to extract data from the SQLite database. But it doesn't work like this:

```
 con = sqlite3.connect('myTable.db')
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users Where user_id= '{0}'".format(curent_user_id)
 a = cur.fetchall() #output: [('1022197197', 'En', '{"JSON_FORMAT_DATA": "bsq83l0gt21xmjp6vcrnf9ea5kuo7y"}')]
 con.close()

 print(a[0])
```

I want the output to be like this: '1022197197'.
How can this be done?

Comment: You should select only required columns instead of doing `SELECT *`, if you have one to one mapping then you can use `fetchone` instead of `fetchall`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *fetchall()* function in your case returns a list of tuples. When you run `print(a[0])` you're only getting the first tuple in the list. It's not the cleanest but try `print((a[0])[0])`.

Also as a side note, to my knowledge the {} format() method you're using is [prone to SQL injection attacks](https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/#passing-safe-query-parameters). I'd change that line to something like:

`c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id", {'user_id': current_user_id})`